# LP / MILP If-Then Statements

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have the following statements for a MILP:

Variables: 
 `c` (can be 1 or 0), `αj` (real numbers with `0 <= αj <= 1`)

I have a linear inequality system for `aj`:

 ∑vj * αj = 0 (with vj = constants)

 ∑αj = c

and I have the following logic:

 If there exists a solution for `c = 1`, the formulation should be infeasible

 If there exists the **only one** solution `c = 0` (each αj must be 0) the formulation should be feasible

I need some more equations or changes so that the logic above holds.

**First idea:**

  When I use an additional constraint `c = 1` the MILP finds a solution for `c = 1` und no solution for `c = 0`. This helps to identify if `c`  can be `1` but this flips the feasible solution space since the solver breaks when `c = 0` which should be the feasible one. Adding  the constraint `c = 0` will not help, since it is not enough that `c = 0` is one potential solution, it must be the only one valid solution.

**Second idea:**

  When I use the objective function `max(c)` i can conclude that

 `IF max(c) = 1 THEN not feasible`  (or `IF max(c) = 0 THEN feasible`)

 However I don't want to use `c` in the objective function.

Is there any other possibility to change the formulation so that the logic above holds?

Comment: [Searching "if then"](https://or.stackexchange.com/search?q=if+then) at [OR.SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/) yields quite a few relevant posts: [Linear programming with if-then-else (big-M)](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/3028/491) and [If-then constraints in MIP programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/2873/491).

Comment: You may consider asking this on [or.se] where it is absolutely on-topic.  You'll just need to check the search mentioned to see if your question is answered already. If not, ask away.

Comment: See also [Single reference for Mixed Integer Programming formulations to linearize, handle logical constraints and disjunctive constraints, do Big M, etc?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/57/491).